# Can't print in portrait

Tags: printing, libreoffice, gedit, canon, adobe-acrobat

Since this morning, I can't print in full size portrait. No matter how I fiddle the printing options, reboot the computer, restart the printer, the hard copy always comes out half size, 2 pages per sheet side.  This happens when I use LibreOffice Writer, Gedit or when printing PDF documents.
I have seen a few questions about this topic but none of the solutions corrected the situation.

I am running on Xubuntu 14.04 and my printer is Canon Pixma MP180

Regards

Comment: did you edit the work options in system-config-printer?

Comment: I am a noob so maybe I did but without knowing it.

Comment: Don't worry :) go there: in a terminal write system-config-printer  -then click on your's printer icon (canon pixma) -then work options -then change "page for edge" to 1. Sorry, my OS isn't in english, so maybe the last commands shall be a bit different. Did it work?

Comment: Everything worked up to "page for edge". I don't see anything that would fit the meaning of the expression. here is the proposed choices:
`Unknown value for media-col: (unknown IPP value tag 0x34)
Choices: [u'media-bottom-margin', u'media-left-margin', u'media-right-margin', u'media-size', u'media-source', u'media-top-margin', u'media-type']
Selecting from choices: media-bottom-margin`

Comment: I don't know where to go from there

Answer (score 1):

did you control those variable, as I ask in the previous comment?
[image: my desktop]

Comment: Yes I did all these verifications before posting the question.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally decided to delete the printer and re-add it and it corrected the issue.

Comment: sure that's the simplest solution :) cheers

Comment: Yes, so easy it is a waste of time to try to figure what is that cause of the problem

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same problem unchecking the "Auto Rotate and Center" option.

[image: Xubuntu 14.10 printer options]